# Editing 2 tables in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, linq

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is that I don't know how to update my 2 tables.

my input works and passes values to **`sendDefence`** and **`sendName`**. But how to change these values in 2 tables?

**ERROR:**

DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

WebGame.Controllers.TowersController.Edit(int id, EditViewModel editViewModel) in TowersController.cs

```
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**EditViewModel.cs**

```
 public class EditViewModel
    {
        public World World { get; set; }
        public Tower Tower { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit.Html**

```
@model WebGame.ViewModel.EditViewModel
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form asp-action="Edit">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="World.WorldId" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="World.Player1Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="World.Player1Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="World.Player1Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Tower.Defence" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Tower.Defence" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Tower.Defence" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, EditViewModel editViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    int? sendDefence = editViewModel.Tower.Defence;
                    string sendName = editViewModel.World.Player1Name;

                    Tower tower = new Tower();
                    tower.Defence = sendDefence;
                    _context.Update(tower);

                    World world = new World();
                    world.Player1Name = sendName;
                    _context.Update(world);

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!TowerExists(editViewModel.World.WorldId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Tower and World are only new object without relation with database and `without ID data`.so actually affected 0 row(s).

```
    Tower tower = new Tower();
    tower.Defence = sendDefence;
    _context.Update(tower);

    World world = new World();
    world.Player1Name = sendName;
    _context.Update(world);
```

you can query first then update value then call SaveChangesAsync.

```
    Tower tower = _context.Tower.First(w=>w.Id == editViewModel.Tower.Id);
    tower.Defence = sendDefence;
    _context.Update(tower);

    World world = _context.World.First(w=>w.Id == editViewModel.World.Id);
    world.Player1Name = sendName;
    _context.Update(world);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like that. 
But how to write it better if it's not the best code at the moment?